# Syntax Highlighter - Issues with Word Wrap

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, syntax-highlighting, word-wrap

**OK, here's the issue :**

- I've been using `SyntaxHighlighter.js` for some code colouring at [Snippet.MX](http://www.snippet.mx)

As you may see, the thing works except for one little details : `Word wrapping` is **not** supported.

**I tried :**

- Adding `white-space: pre-wrap;` to the `pre` element
- Adding the appropriate CSS3 property
- Using the jquery hack as suggested by others (you'll notice it at the very bottom of the page)

Any ideas?